# ReactNative Status bar disable Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to disable status bar in Android. The command I use works, but on any event like reload, soft keyboard show etc. - the status bar shows up. How to make it not showing ever? Code I use:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />
```

Comment: If you don't need it to ever show could you remove `<StatusBar />` entirely?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody If the StatusBar component is not provided, the status bar will be visible by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems related to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5991). (A fix should be land in 0.22)

> **[Android] Hidden  reappears after screen lock #5991**
>
> I'm trying out the new cross-platform StatusBar component. One thing I noticed is that if I lock my Android phone screen on a view with , the status bar is visible again upon unlocking the phone.

I might think that focus on native components cause this bug too.

Comment: 0.22 will be released this monday (March 21st), you can use 0.22.0-rc4 in the meantime.